# Can I do a Nested List Sub Menu Without Using JavaScript?

Tags: html, css, list, drop-down-menu

Is it possible when using nested lists to create a drop down hover sub menu without using JavaScript?

I must use `<li>` items and a nested `<ul>` for this.

I know how to do this with Javascript's mouseover, but wondered if it was possible to reveal the submenu when hovering over `About` with just CSS?

```css
li {
  list-style: none
}

.nav-menu-items {
  display: flex
}

.menu-item {
  padding: 1rem
}

.submenu {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-menu-items">
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-3">HOME</li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-2">ABOUT
    <ul class="submenu about-submenu">
      <li class="submenu-item ubmenu-item-1"><a class="submenu-link">Our Team</a></li>
      <li class="submenu-item ubmenu-item-2"><a class="submenu-link">Other stuff</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-3"><a class="td navigation--link">STUFF</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-4"><a class="td navigation--link">STUFF</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-5"><a class="td navigation--link">STUFF</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have already mentioned, use `:hover` states and change `display` attribute, something like this:

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-menu-items {
  display: flex;
}

.menu-item {
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-item:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
}

.submenu {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-menu-items">
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-3">HOME</li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-2">ABOUT
    <ul class="submenu about-submenu">
      <li class="submenu-item ubmenu-item-1"><a class="submenu-link">Our Team</a></li>
      <li class="submenu-item ubmenu-item-2"><a class="submenu-link">Other stuff</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-3"><a class="td navigation--link">STUFF</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-4">Menu STUFF
    <ul class="submenu about-submenu">
      <li class="submenu-item ubmenu-item-1"><a class="submenu-link">Menu Stuff 1</a></li>
      <li class="submenu-item ubmenu-item-2"><a class="submenu-link">Other Menu stuff</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-5"><a class="td navigation--link">STUFF</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can set its `display` to none and only display it, when hovering the parent li:

```css
li {list-style: none}

.nav-menu-items {display: flex}

.menu-item {padding: 1rem}

.submenu {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
}
   
li:hover .submenu{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-menu-items">
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-3">HOME</li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-2">ABOUT
    <ul class="submenu about-submenu">
      <li class="submenu-item ubmenu-item-1"><a class="submenu-link">Our Team</a></li>
      <li class="submenu-item ubmenu-item-2"><a class="submenu-link">Other stuff</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-3"><a class="td navigation--link">STUFF</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-4"><a class="td navigation--link">STUFF</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-5"><a class="td navigation--link">STUFF</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, and you can also add some nice animations to it, by hiding it through the **opacity** **property** and not the **display** one. Then use **nested selectors** to trigger the visibility

**.my_parent_div:hover .my_child_div{}**

**Example:**

```css
li {list-style: none}

.nav-menu-items {display: flex}

.menu-item {padding: 1rem}

.submenu {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  opacity:0;
  transform:scaleY(0);
  transform-origin:top;
  pointer-events:none;
  transition:ease-in-out .2s;
}
.menu-item:hover .submenu{
  opacity:1;
  transform:scaleY(1);
  pointer-events:all;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-menu-items">
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-3">HOME</li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-2">ABOUT
    <ul class="submenu about-submenu">
      <li class="submenu-item ubmenu-item-1"><a class="submenu-link">Our Team</a></li>
      <li class="submenu-item ubmenu-item-2"><a class="submenu-link">Other stuff</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-3"><a class="td navigation--link">STUFF</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-4"><a class="td navigation--link">STUFF</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-5"><a class="td navigation--link">STUFF</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** I have used the **pointer-events** property to prevent it from being "clickable" even when it's hidden, you could use the **visibility** property instead, I simply prefer this one more.

Answer (score 1):

here's a simple example of how it could be done:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
    font-family: monospace;
}

ul {
  background: darkorange;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

li {
    color: #fff;
  background: darkorange;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 1rem;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
  
li a {
  color: #fff;
}

li:hover,
li:focus-within {
    background: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li:focus-within a {
  outline: none;
}

ul li ul {
    background: orange;
    visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  min-width: 5rem;
    position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
    left: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover > ul,
ul li:focus-within > ul,
ul li ul:hover,
ul li ul:focus {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block
}

ul li ul li {
    clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You could apply the same principle you described about `mouseover`, using `hover` and `visibility`.

Add this to your CSS:

```
.menu-item:hover .submenu {
   visibility: visible;
   opacity: 1;
}

.submenu {
  transition: 0.32s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Note: It's better to use visibilibty instead of `display` in this case, because you can add `transition` with `opacity` to it, creating animation effects.